# Is this character development with Lui Kang accurate to the source material?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, mortal-kombat-legacy

Machinama has finally released a trailer for Season 2 of Kevin Tancharoen's hit web series ***Mortal Kombat: Legacy***. It seems from the trailer that Shang Tsung recruits Kang to fight alongside the Outerworld contestants against the humans.

Is this based on some new development in the MK franchise story line or is it an original serial story arc?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the Season 1 episode, a foreword by the Director notes that the series has moved beyond the core game story line(s).

[image]

The storyline with Liu Kang diverges from the story previously seen in the Mortal Kombat games and movie adaptations of the games, in that Liu Kang is not the protagonist or main Earthrealm Champion. In fact, MK2 (the game) states that Liu Kang became the Earthrealm Champion for the Shaolin monks because Kang Lao declined to fight. In Legacy, this has been flipped around, with Kang Lao becoming the Shaolin monk to fight for Earthrealm.

In the MK storylines, many Earth fighters are tempted and fall for the Outworld recruitment tactics. This time, Liu Kang falls.